# How to use annotate() with Haystack in Django?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have a function that search with hatstack, and I need to get the comments of each object that haystack get in the array, I have this:

```
def search(request):
if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
    q = request.GET['q']
    results = SearchQuerySet().auto_query(q)
    things = []
    for r in results:
        things.append(r.object)
    return render_to_response('resultados.html',
        {'things': things, 'query': q}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How I append to the results the number of comments that each object have?

If I add annotate, debugger throw me: SearchQuerySet has not 'annotate' attribute

Answer (score 3):

`SearchQuerySet` isn't the ORM query set you're familiar with. It only imitates it. Annotations doesn't make sense with search engines as well. You need to put already prepared data to an index.

Just make another query using ORM.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to send to the template just one queryset after i do a search and then a query using ORM?

Comment: I mean relate each result of The sesrchqueryset with the one who The ORM query ser retrieve to me?

Comment: Just pass normal python `dict` with both sets combined in easy-to-iterate form. The shape of such dictionary will depend on the template code which uses it.